# RDP Client to better manage multiple sessions? (Like a Virtual Machine Control Panel)

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm on a x64 Windows 7 Machine and I have to regularly connect to multiple Win2003 and Win2008 servers through RDP.

I use the built-in RDP Client, but having multiple ones open clutters the taskbar and sometimes I don't see if I'm already connected and connect again etc.

I just wonder if there is a tool that gives me a view a bit similar to how VMWare displays PCs, that is with a sidebar of all my saved sessions, (optionally) displaying a thumbnail.

Essentially this:
[image: RDP Example]

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Microsoft's [RDCMan](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4603c621-6de7-4ccb-9f51-d53dc7e48047&displaylang=en) (Remote Desktop Connection Manager). Allows you to group sessions (start all at once) and offers thumbnail views. Works well and I use it on some of my machines.

On my main work machine I use the free version of [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/). Not only does it do remote desktop but also offers VNC, telnet, ICA, SSH, HTTP/S. A pretty solid all-in-one approach.

Comment: I like mRemote too.

Comment: Didn't know RDCMan, cool. Does what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools for this. I use [RoyalTS](http://code4ward.net/main/).